# How can we create a room in video conference app using janus webrtc..?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, webrtc, janus-gateway

Hi all I am new in programming I started to do a project in video conferencing app using JANUS webRTC. Backend I plan to use node for signup and sign routes but I am stuck in creating API for room. frond end I plan to use Reactjs someone please help me to move on..